# Cannot install deb files

Tags: software-center

Whenever I try to install an deb files the file opens in the software centre but says internal error cannot be opened. Please help?

Comment: Care to provide the exact error message?

Comment: Please include what it says on 'sudo dpkg - i packet_name.deb'

Answer (score 3):

Try re-downloading the package, and run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb
```

This command will only work if you have all the dependencies for that package installed.

If `dpkg` complains about missing dependencies, try running `sudo apt-get install -f` and then try the first command again.