# Arduino Deb file don't installed

Tags: package-management

I have installed the Arduino deb file form [here](http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/arduino/arduino-core_1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1_all.deb) :

[image]
so when i try install deb file downloaded i get this feedback:
[image]

my Ubuntu version info is:

```
so@so-notebook:~/Videos$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

***Update***:

by [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245829/cannot-install-deb-files) i get this feedback:

```
so@so-notebook:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i  arduino-core_1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1_all.deb
[sudo] password for so: 
Selecting previously unselected package arduino-core.
(Reading database ... 334755 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack arduino-core_1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking arduino-core (2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of arduino-core:
 arduino-core depends on gcc-avr (>= 4.7.0); however:
  Package gcc-avr is not installed.
 arduino-core depends on avrdude (>= 6.3-2); however:
  Package avrdude is not installed.
 arduino-core depends on avr-libc (>= 1.8.0); however:
  Package avr-libc is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package arduino-core (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 arduino-core
```

so how could i install it via `aptitude` by automatically install those packages?

Update:

i have tried  this by @Thomas_Ward suggestion:

> ... have you simply just tried running sudo apt install arduino-core
>   after running sudo apt update? Sounds like your system isn't able to
>   determine the dependencies, but you shouldn't have to download the
>   .deb manually to install like you're doing. (Since it's in the
>   repositories)

```
so@so-notebook:~/Downloads$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alessandro-strada/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniel-marynicz/filemanager-actions/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB] 
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                  
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/haraldhv/shotcut/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:12 http://apt.keepsolid.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                  
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tractor-team/tractor/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/lives/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Fetched 88.7 kB in 4s (20.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

but again i get this feedback:

```
so@so-notebook:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i  arduino-core_1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1_all.deb
(Reading database ... 336049 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack arduino-core_1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking arduino-core (2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1) over (2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of arduino-core:
 arduino-core depends on gcc-avr (>= 4.7.0); however:
  Package gcc-avr is not installed.
 arduino-core depends on avrdude (>= 6.3-2); however:
  Package avrdude is not installed.
 arduino-core depends on avr-libc (>= 1.8.0); however:
  Package avr-libc is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package arduino-core (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 arduino-core
```

Thanks.

Comment: ... have you simply just tried running `sudo apt install arduino-core` after running `sudo apt update`?  Sounds like your system isn't able to determine the dependencies, but you shouldn't have to *download* the `.deb` manually to install like you're doing.  (Since it's *in* the repositories)

Comment: The question is updated

Comment: You didn't follow @ThomasWard's instructions correctly. Try again.

Comment: @user535733, i have tried those he said, which part i  have missed?

Comment: @modern that I said to **run exactly `sudo apt install arduino-core`** and **to NOT use `dpkg` directly to install from the `.deb` you downloaded**.  Because this is already in the repos you don't need to download the .deb, AND it'll automatically handle getting dependencies from the repositories properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest Arduino IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025753/how-to-install-latest-arduino-ide) Also please add universe pocket to your *sources.list* with `sudo add-apt-repository universe`.